# How can i navigate to the old Desktop which is now in the second drive position?

Tags: desktop-computer

My computer failed and i put in a new hard drive and have a new desktop. However i have the old primary drive with what is left acting as the second drive. Does anyone know the path to access the old desktop directory on the broken drive?  I have searched for the directory already to no avail.
As I want to visit that directory to see what all i had on the old desktop so i may set it up similarly.

Comment: Keep in mind that shortcuts on the (old) desktop, especially to programs, are unlikely to work on your new desktop.

Comment: Please edit your question/tags to indicate what OS was installed on the old drive. It's impossible to answer the question without this information.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **user**, then select the name, which should be your user name, then **Desktop**.

i.e **/Users/*****/Desktop** I am assuming your files should on default be in **C: Drive**